# Using a single while loop vs a while and if combination

Tags: java, loops

I have created a while loop that takes in a user value b and checks for two conditions. Although I got my code right I originally tried to do this with a single while loop combining the two conditions but it didn't work. My incrementer i++ either counts once or loops forever depending on where I put it.

Is there a way that this could work using a while statement combining the conditions?

**Does not work**

```
        //Declare variables
        int i = 0 ;         //Counter Variable.
        int positive = 0 ;  //Holds the result of our positive sum.

        while ( ( i < b ) && ( i % 10 == 0 ) )  //While i is less than the users number.

            {

                positive = i ;
                System.out.println ( positive ) ;
                i++ ;   //Incrementer

            }
```

**This Works**

```
        //Declare variables
        int i = 0 ;         //Counter Variable.
        int positive = 0 ;  //Holds the result of our positive sum.

        while ( i < b ) //While i is less than the users number.

            {

                if ( i % 10 == 0 )

                    {

                        positive = i ;
                        System.out.println ( positive ) ;

                    }

                i++ ;
            }
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? ie, what is your expected output for a given input?

Comment: what is the value of `b`

Comment: No, because they are 2 separate things. One is a loop to go through a range of numbers, and the other is a condition to print. If you combine them, it will just stop as soon as one of the conditions doesn't work, as you experienced.

Comment: The first one will leave the loop after executing the body the first time because 1 % 10 == 0 is false.

Comment: If user enters 100, then it should print out all numbers between 1 and 100 that are also divisible by 10, so 10, 20, 30 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ( ( i < b ) && ( i % 10 == 0 ) )
```

loop will run only once because as soon as value of i changes from 0 to 1 because of incrementer

```
( i % 10 == 0 ) will fail.
```

Whereas in

```
 while ( i < b )
```

code is checking if i is less than b or not and

> if ( i % 10 == 0 )

is getting handled as separate condition.

Comment: Oh I see, I assumed it would retest the condition, so in the first it breaks my loop and returns 0 to me. It doesn't fail in second code because it is just counting 0 to 99 and in each iteration it is then checking.

Answer (score 0):

Those two chunks of code aren't equivalent and you can't really make them equivalent. In your first block of code, your comment takes into account the first condition, but not the second. You have two conditions there. Both of them *must* be true for the loop to continue. As soon as one of those conditions is false, the looping stops. So as soon as `i % 10 == 0` returns false, the loop ends.

However, you can also solve this by incrementing `i` by 10 at each loop. So you could have something like and it would produce the same output:

```
int i = 0 ;
int positive = 0 ;
while (i < b){
    positive = i;
    System.out.println ( positive ) ;
    i += 10;
}
```

Comment: would be even simpler with a `for` loop. `for (int i = 0; i < b; i += 10) {}`

Comment: Also, this is actually wrong, `positive` will always be 0, just use `i`

Comment: Yeah for sure it's better as a for loop, but he asked about while loops specifically so I used that. I don't know what you mean with your second comment. It gets incremented.

Comment: Fair enough on the loop type. You're printing out the variable `positive`, which is always 0.

Comment: That's what OP's code does, I just copied it. EDIT: oh wow I'm an idiot. That's not what it does. My bad. I'll edit my post.